# csv file & awk: change second column entry if the first column matches, print complete file afterwards

Tags: text-processing, awk, posix

I'm writing my own password manager, which I want to be strictly POSIX compliant. To simplify: I have this file, `file.csv`:

```
mastodon;password2
bla;test
test;test
posteo;tewtasdwqrr
```

Basically, I want to have a function which takes two arguments: it should select the first argument from the first column and from that line, it should replace the second column entry with the second argument.

For instance: `f "bla" "etewtw"` would change the password of the last entry to `etewtw`.

I tried to use awk, which also somewhat works:

```
awk -F ";" -v acc="bla" -v newpw="etewtw" \
'$1 ~ acc { $2=newpw; print $1";"$2 } END {print;} ' file.csv
```

Basically, I tried to set the second column to the `newpw` argument if the first column matches on the `acc` argument. After changing the stream, I want to print the complete stream, which doesn't work. The above is obviously not the correct solution, but I don't know how to fix that.

The output is:

```
bla;etewtw
posteo;tewtasdwqrr
```

So it is kinda successful, the entry was changed (at least in the stream, but actually changing the file is not difficult).

However, two problems arise:

1. Entries are missing in the output. Namely `mastodon;password2` and `test;test`. I expect  those to a) stay at the same line and b) be  unchanged.
2. If I want to change the last line, it is always wrong. For instance, if I use `awk -F ";" -v acc="posteo" -v newpw="test" '$1 ~ acc { $2=newpw; print $1";"$2 } END {print;} '` instead, the result is:

```
posteo;test
posteo test
```

which is not what I want. I want the last line to be no different to any other line.

Answer (score 6):

You need either of these to have your name and password treated as literal strings:

```
acc='bla' newpw='etewtw' awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"; acc=ENVIRON["acc"]; newpw=ENVIRON["newpw"]}
    $1 == acc{$2=newpw} 1
' file.csv

awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"; acc=ARGV[1]; newpw=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""}
    $1 == acc{$2=newpw} 1
' 'bla' 'etewtw' file.csv
```

You need this approach because variables passed with `-v` expand escape sequences. So, if either of the variables you pass contain a backslash, for example `foo\tbar`, then the `\t` in the middle will be expanded and treated as a literal tab character.

See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The only modification I would see is necessary is that you have a `print` statement in the `END` section, but missing one for non-matching lines. What instead you should do is

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' -v acc='bla' -v newpw='etewtw' '$1 == acc {$2=newpw}1' file.csv
```

i.e. simply replace field Nr. 2 with the new password, and in general print the (possibly modified) line (the shorthand notation for that is the `1`). With this, I also succeeded in changing the record on the last line.

Also, it would seem wise to make your condition an exact match instead of a regex, you never know if one account name may contain a string that matches another account name (as in `admin` and `webadmin`, e.g.).

Comment: That will fail if/when either field contains a backslash since variables initialized with `-v` expand escape sequences. You need to set shell variables and use ENVIRON[] or pass the strings as command line arguments before the input file to have them treated exactly as-is.

Comment: @EdMorton that is true. While I don't think the first field is likely to do so, the second field may very well (or, indeed, should) contain special characters that may be mis-interpreted. I see you already posted a robust answer, so I will refrain from editing mine.

Comment: Yeah, I might've not bothered commenting if it wasn't for the password field. You have a second issue I just noticed though - you're using double quotes instead of single around your variables and so asking the shell to interpret them so `newpw="foo$PWD"`, for example, wouldn't behave as you want. Always use single quotes around strings and scripts unless you **NEED** double quotes instead (e.g. to let variables expand) and then use double quotes unless you **NEED** no quotes (e.g. for globbing/file name expansion).

Comment: You are right. I copy-and-pasted that part from the OPs approach, and didn't check that thoroughly enough. I need to be more careful there, thank you for pointing it out. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @toogley I would recommend accepting Ed Morton's answer instead of mine because of the variable expansion issues discussed in the comments here. The accepted answer should be as little error-prone as possible for use by the "unsuspecting" reader who may have stumbled across it while googling.